# Evaluating $\prod^{100}_{k=1}\left[1+2\cos \frac{2\pi \cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate$$\prod^{100}_{k=1}\left[1+2\cos \frac{2\pi \cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$$

My attempt:

$$1+2\cos 2\theta= 1+2(1-2\sin^2\theta)=3-4\sin^2\theta$$

$$=\frac{3\sin \theta-4\sin^3\theta}{\sin \theta}=\frac{\sin 3\theta}{\sin \theta}$$

I did not understand how to solve after that. Help required.

Comment: A sum of cosines is the Real part of a sum of exponentials... not sure that helps.

Comment: This is strange: [the partial sums are produce a linear plot up to $k=90$ where it drops for some time](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+cos((2pi*k*3%5Ek)%2F(3%5E100%2B1))+from+k%3D1+to+100)...

Comment: Where is the problem from, by the way?

Comment: Will be it be $$\prod^{100}_{k=1}\left[1+2\cos \frac{2\pi k\cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Not that strange, considering that $\frac{2\pi k\cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}$ is tiny until $k$ gets close to $100$. Consider that $\cos(\epsilon)\geq 1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ by Taylor's theorem, so most of the terms will be very close to $1$ if $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: @jacky: Just to make sure, you meant $\displaystyle\prod_{k = 1}^{100}\left[1+2\cos\dfrac{2\pi k \cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$ and not $\displaystyle\prod_{k = 1}^{100}\left[1+2\cos\dfrac{2\pi \cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$, i.e. you meant to have the $k$ in the numerator, correct?

Comment: Try a Taylor-expansion of that sine-thing you got at the end and look at the values for some k's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear if you are asking about $$\prod^{100}_{k=1}\left[1+2\cos \frac{2\pi \cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$$ or about $$\prod^{100}_{k=1}\left[1+2\cos \frac{2\pi k\cdot 3^k}{3^{100}+1}\right]$$

I will assume it is the former. At the moment, that is in the body of your question, while the latter is in the title. If it's the former, then using the trig identity you found, you have a telescoping product which then further simplifies nicely: $$
\begin{align}
\prod^{100}_{k=1}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{k+1}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{k}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{2}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{1}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{3}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{2}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\cdots\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{101}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{100}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{101}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3^{1}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3\cdot3^{100}}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3\left(\cdot3^{100}+1\right)-3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=\frac{\sin\left(3\pi-\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi\frac{3}{3^{100}+1}\right)}\\[1pc]
&=1
\end{align}$$

Note near the end that $\sin(3\pi-X)=\sin(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$z=\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{3^n+1}\bigg)+i\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{3^n+1}\bigg)$$

Then $z^{3^n+1}=1$ and also $\displaystyle 2\cos \bigg(\frac{2\pi\cdot 3^k}{3^n+1}\bigg)=z^{3^k}+\frac{1}{z^{3^k}}$

Write $$\prod^{n}_{k=1}\bigg[1+2\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi\cdot 3^k}{3^n+1}\bigg)\bigg]$$
$$=\bigg(1+z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}\bigg)\bigg(1+z^9+\frac{1}{z^9}\bigg)\cdots \cdots \bigg(1+z^{3n}+\frac{1}{z^{3n}}\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{(1+z^3+z^6)(1+z^9+z^{18})\cdots \cdots (1+z^{3^n}+(z^{3^n})^2)}{z^{3+9+\cdots \cdots +3^n}}$$

Multiply both Nr and Dr by $(1-z^3)$

$$=\frac{1-z^{3^{n+1}}}{(1-z^3)\cdot z^{3\frac{(3^n-1)}{2}}}= \frac{1-z^{-3}}{-(1-z^3)\cdot z^{-3}}=1.$$

$\text{Simplification}:\;\; $ From $z^{3n+1}=1\Rightarrow z^{3n}=z^{-1}$

And $$z^{3\frac{(3^n-1)}{2}}=z^{-3}\cdot z^{3\frac{(3^+1)}{2}}=z^{-3}\cdot \bigg(z^{\frac{(3^+1)}{2}}\bigg)^3=-z^3$$